# error installing spacy-readability in python 3.7

Tags: python, windows, spacy, python-3.7

I have a problem installing spacy-readability. It gives me the following error:

```
Command ""c:\program files (x86)\python37-32\python.exe" "c:\program files (x86)\python37-32\lib\site-packages\pip" in
stall --ignore-installed --no-user --prefix C:\Users\USR~1\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-fduabwfn\overlay --no-w
arn-script-location --no-binary :none: --only-binary :none: -i https://pypi.org/simple -- setuptools wheel>0.32.0.<0.3
3.0 Cython cymem>=2.0.2,<2.1.0 preshed>=2.0.1,<2.1.0 murmurhash>=0.28.0,<1.1.0 thinc==7.0.0.dev6" failed with error code 1 in None
```

My python version is 3.7.2, already tried:

1. downgrade setuptools to version 39 (before it was 40)
2. change python version
3. download of the whl and installation by pip install (before I was using, and I'd still like to use, pycharm)
4. installation of an older version of spacy-readability(still the same
   error)

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution: download the following whl from [here](https://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#spacy) and spacy-readability whl from [here](https://pypi.org/project/spacy-readability/#files) and install them with the following command:

```
pip install [file.whl] --user --no-deps
```